# Plotting google maps with local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have created an application that allows a user to plot a flag on google maps upon a click event although once the page is refreshed all of flags are lost. I want to be able to keep the data the user has input using local storage, can anyone point me in a direction or show me sample code of how they would handle this problem? thanks.
**Basic google maps code without local storage**

```
var map;
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(54.906435, -1.383944);

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:13,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

        //creating the event for placing the marker
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });

}
//Funcion to place the marker on the map (flag)
function placeMarker(location) {

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    icon:'flag.png',
    map: map,
  });
  //open information window once marker is placed
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'User has placed warning'
  });
  infowindow.open(map,marker);

  //zoom into the marker
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
  map.setZoom(17);
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  });

}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick ;)

```js
function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:13,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

        //creating the event for placing the marker
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    writeToStorage(event.latLng);
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });
  
  setupStorage();
  readFromStorage();
}

function setupStorage() {
  if(typeof(localStorage) === "undefined") {
    // If localStorage isn't supported, fake it.
    // Won't persist between sessions.
    localStorage = {};
  }
  
  localStorage.locations = localStorage.locations || [];
}

function writeToStorage(location) {
  localStorage.locations.push(location);
}

function readFromStorage() {
  localStorage.locations.forEach(function(location) {
    placeMarker(location);
  });
}

//Funcion to place the marker on the map (flag)
function placeMarker(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    icon:'flag.png',
    map: map,
  });
  //open information window once marker is placed
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'User has placed warning'
  });
  infowindow.open(map,marker);

  //zoom into the marker
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
  map.setZoom(17);
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  });

}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Let me know if you have any trouble understanding any of it.

Comment: Thanks for replying, When I use that code the map shows with correct zooming but I can't plot anything?

Comment: Setup a jsfiddle if you can.  Also check your console logs, i have a feeling the points may be plotted before initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

```
var map = {};
var polyOptions = {};
```

$(document).ready(function () {

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('MapDiagram'), {
            zoom: 5.4,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -10),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            zoomControl: true
        });
       polyOptions = {
            strokeWeight: 0,
            fillOpacity: 0.45,
            editable: true
        };
});

map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(coord1, coord2));